# Getting 403 Forbidden error when using custom login page with spring security

Tags: spring-security, http-status-code-403

I am learning Spring Security. I have created custom login page and using Database authentication. When I try to login to the app, getting 403 Forbidden error. Pasting my spring security config file below:

```
<security:http auto-config="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/login.jsp" access="hasRole('ROLE_ANONYMOUS')"/>
    <security:form-login login-page="/login.jsp" login-processing-url="/login"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager>
        <security:password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder"/>
     </security:authentication-provider> -->

     <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"/>
        <security:password-encoder hash="bcrypt"/>
     </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>

<bean id="passwordEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.password.NoOpPasswordEncoder">
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springSecurityDB"/>
    <property name="username" value="root"/>
    <property name="password" value="password"/>
</bean>
```

Below is my login.jsp:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>My Login Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="login" name="loginForm" method="POST">
    Username : <input type="text" name="username"/>
    Password: <input type="password" name="password"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Thanks,
Aanchal

Answer (score 0):

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
```

`403 Forbidden` means the login user does not have enough permission. According to your setting above , he needs to have the `ROLE_USER` permission.

Since you are using the default JDBC UserService , it needs to work with these set of [table schema](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#nsa-jdbc-user-service-attributes) behind scenes. So following the schema and assign 'ROLE_USER' to the login user and then try again. (e.g. perhaps insert a record `('someUser', 'ROLE_USER')` to the `authorities` table ? )

Comment: Hi Ken, my database table already has a user with ROLE_USER as the role. This was working fine with spring security's login page. It stopped working when I provided my custom login page.